# How to disable the access to public classes of a jar?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am developing a SDK named `QsjhSDK.aar`.  It contains another library named `ALibrary.jar` inside. Now I want others having no access to the classes in `ALibrary.jar` while using `QsjhSDK.aar`.  Is it possible, and if so, how?
In addition,I don't have the source code of ALibrary.jar so I can't make the classes in it to be `protected` or `default`.

Comment: I would think that using the ```protected``` access modifier on classes that you want limited access to in ```ALibrary.jar``` would only allow access to said classes from other classes within the package.

Comment: Sorry ,I forgot to say that I don't have the source code of ALibrary.jar.